# How to classify a good question and a bad question with multiple upvotes?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I'm catching this question in my queue: [Not equal to condition in mysql query codeigniter [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644582/not-equal-to-condition-in-mysql-query-codeigniter).

It has:

- 46k views,
- 6 upvotes and 0 downvotes,
- 4 answers and none of them has any downvote,
- The accepted answer has 16 upvotes,
- Duplicate content (by a user who has PHP gold tag).

Since my background doesn't focus on PHP, I want to know why should that question be deleted (it already has 3 votes)? Just because of duplicate?

---

Another look, imagine if this question is researched by 46k users who have less than 200 reputation, we can get 46k advertisement views, right?

Comment: Duplicate questions aren't necessarily _bad questions_.

Comment: The duplicate target is around 35.5 views/day and this one around 25.6 views/day so I don't think we should delete this one since it seems to be a good singpost that bring visitor and it seems to be useful since it gather upvotes ... I would delete trivial duplicates with low quality answers that doesn't bring a lot of visitors

Comment: A very similar question was asked 4 year earlier.  The asker and the answerers could have invested a bit of time to search. Why people voted to delete though is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like an ideal candidate for a merge. Flag a mod to do so, and thereafter perhaps edit the answers somewhat so that they still apply to the chosen remaining question.

Comment: Thanks! If I reach at 15k reputation, can I protect a question from deletion?